# 12/24-hour mode conflict

Tags: android, simpledateformat, android-timepicker

I am a French Android developer, so using `Locale.getDefault()` causes my `DateFormat` to use a 24-hour mode. But, when I set manually my device to 12-hour mode via the setting menu, `DateFormat` keeps going in a 24-hour format.

On the contrary, `TimePicker`s are set according to my own 12/24-hour setting.

Is there any way to make `DateFormat`s behave the same way as `TimePicker`s ?

**EDIT:**

Here is my `DateFormat` declaration:

```
timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

And here is where I set my `TimePicker`to 12 or 24-hour mode.

```
tp.setIs24HourView(android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat((Context) this));
```

**My Solution:**

According to @Meno Hochschild's answer below, here is how I solved this tricky problem:

```
boolean is24hour = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat((Context) this);
tp.setIs24HourView(is24hour); // tp is the TimePicker
timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
if (timeFormat instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
    String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) timeFormat).toPattern();
    if (is24hour) {
        timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern.replace("h", "H").replace(" a",""), Locale.getDefault());
    }
    else {
        timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern.replace("H", "h"), Locale.getDefault());
    }
}
```

After this, `timeFormat` will correctly format dates whether your device is set to display times in a 24-hour format or in a 12-hour one. And the `TimePicker` will be correctly set too.

Comment: Do you specify your own format? Pay attention between 'hh' and 'HH' http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Please post some code. The part where you set the SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: If you could please post the string you are using for SimpleDateFormat that would be helpful.

Comment: Ew, my bad. It isn't a `SimpleDateFormat`, but a `DateFormat`. Just edited to correct this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have specified a pattern in `SimpleDateFormat` then you have fixed the 12/24-hour mode, either 12-hour-mode in case of pattern symbol "h" (1-12) or 24-hour-mode in case of pattern symbol "H" (0-23). The alternatives "k" and "K" are similar with slightly different ranges.

That said, specifying a pattern makes your format independent from device setting!

The alternative would be to use [DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance%28int,%20int%29) which makes the time style dependent on system locale (if `Locale.getDefault()` might change - or you have to deploy a mechanism how to ask the current device locale and then to set in Android-Java `Locale.setDefault()`).

Another idea **specific for Android** is to ask directly the system settings using the string constant [TIME_12_24](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#TIME_12_24) and then to specify a pattern dependent on this setting. This also seems to be possible by special method [DateFormat.is24HourFormat()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#is24HourFormat%28android.content.Context%29) (note for your attention that Android has TWO different classes with name `DateFormat`). Concrete example for this approach:

```
boolean twentyFourHourStyle = 
  android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat((Context) this);
DateFormat df = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
if (df instanceof SimpleDateFormat) {
  String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) df).toPattern();
  if (twentyFourHourStyle) {
    df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern.replace("h", "H"), Locale.getDefault());
  } else {
    df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern.replace("H", "h"), Locale.getDefault());
  }
} else {
  // nothing to do or change
}
```

You are of course free to refine the code for possible occurrences of k and K or watch out for use of literals h and H (then parse for apostrophs to ignore such parts in replace-method).

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't specified any pattern. I'm using `java.text.DateFormat` constants, as shown above.

Comment: @RichouHunter I have now updated my answer giving a possible solution based on the fact that most `DateFormat`-objects are internally really `SimpleDateFormat`-objects.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that `DateFormat` were internally `SimpleDateFormat`. However, I just added one more `replace()` statement to remove the "AM/PM" marker is case of a 24-hour format. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RichouHunter Good catch for AM/PM-marker. Tip: You should study the created patterns for different locales (from android repository, coming originally from CLDR) to get more safety about replace-mechanism.

Comment: Is there any other time format than "HH:mm" and "hh:mm a"? It seems a bit disturbing for me imagining other ways to format times…

Comment: @RichouHunter I have not studied [CLDR-data](http://unicode.org/Public/cldr/23/) yet. And Android repositories are often device-dependent and sometimes deviate voluntarily from CLDR, so there is no absolute guarantee, hence my tip for extended tests.

Answer (score 1):

The Original Solution, doesn't work well always. My solution is easier and elegant:

Locale.US By default is 12 hours, then we set as 12 hours.

We check if the user has checked 24 hours format, then we set a Locale with 24 hours as default.

```
boolean twentyFourHourStyle = android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context);
DateFormat timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.US);
if (twentyFourHourStyle) {
    timeFormat = DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT,Locale.FRANCE);
}
```

Solved with 3 lines ;)

Comment: Please put an explanation with your answer.

Comment: Welkom to SO! Please put an explanation with your answer, in what way this solves the original question: "Is there any way to make DateFormats behave the same way as TimePickers".

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use correct DateFormat class.

Use android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);

This correctly updates, when you change the Time 12/24 format in Settings.

Do not use: java.text.DateFormat.  This does not work.

e.g. Date date = new Date();
String time = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context).format(date);

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is an old problem but I'm here because DateFormat.getTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT) wasn't working for me either. It was fine with an API 26 (Android O) AVD but it wasn't working with my old API 16 and API 19 devices (Android 4). So it looks like the issue is just a bug with the older code. I'm now using android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat() combined with android.text.format.DateFormat.is24HourFormat() to get the correct time picker. That works on both my AVD and both my old devices.